# change special elements of matrix without making the other elements a gain

Tags: matlab, element

I want to know if it is possible to change the element of matrix without enumerate all other elements of that matrix.

for example I have a matrix (D) with 1900 rows and 1500 columns and 5 in third dimension. for example when I  write the code:

```
D(1,2,[2,4])=[1 0];
```

It again makes new matrix D with a little change that I wanted. Is it possible that it changes just in those elements without making the other elements again.

Comment: I don't understand your question, what output do you expect?

Comment: I ask it because I have 300 iterations and in every iteration two elements of matrix change so making it again consumes time.

Comment: How do you come to the conclusion that `it again makes new matrix D`?

Comment: When your code is to slow, it is definitely not caused by that line of code. Try `profile` to identify the bottleneck.

Comment: I hope to explain it. when I change only two elements of matrix D by above code. Matlab make matrix D again. however I want to only replace those specific elements in previous matrix. because  I think making it again is very time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way with [`linear indexing`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511) -

```
dim1_idx = 1;
dim2_idx = 2;
dim3_idx = [2,4];

[m,n,r] = size(D);
D( dim1_idx+(dim2_idx-1)*m + (dim3_idx-1)*m*n ) = [0,1]
```

You can introduce [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) for a bit more *readability* -

```
D( sub2ind([m,n],dim1_idx,dim2_idx) + (dim3_idx-1)*m*n ) = [0,1]
```

Verify output -

```
>> D = rand(5,4,4);

dim1_idx = 1;
dim2_idx = 2;
dim3_idx = [2,4];

[m,n,r] = size(D);
D( dim1_idx+(dim2_idx-1)*m + (dim3_idx-1)*m*n ) = [0,1];
>> D(1,2,2)
ans =
     0
>> D(1,2,4)
ans =
     1
```

Comment: Yes it is true. but if you remove (;) you will see this code makes D again with other intact elements.

Comment: @user196345 That `;` is to hide the display of elements, it's not "making" again. I think you need to read MATLAB docs on basics thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding how matlab behaves is wrong.

Take the example:

```
D=rand(1900,1500,5);
D(1,2,[2,4])=[1 0]; %Here the original data structure is updated, no new copy of D is created.
```

There is only one exception, when you still keep the original matrix in another variable:

```
M=rand(1900,1500,5);
D=M; %Typically, such calls only cause a shallow copy not actually replicating M
D(1,2,[2,4])=[1 0]; %Now a copy has to be created, because you are still holding the unmodified original
```